# How to extract filename and other properties from multipart form data prior to uploading file to azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-storage

I want to extract the and set the filename based on application logic on server prior to uploading file to azure..

My current scenario: Client -> Application Web Api -> Azure Storage

Following is code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadProfilePic()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        AzureStorageCls = new MyAzureStorage(WebApiApplication.AllowedImageExtensions);

//Need to set file name based on custom logic prior to upload of image

//Below method calls the  pRequest.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider) of custom MultipartStreamProvider
        BlobStorage BlobImage = await AzureStorageCls.UploadImageToAzure(modifiedFileName, Request);

        return Ok();

    }
```

We want to customize the file name that we send to azure blob storage based on ids

But as i know now we can get all properties only after calling ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider) in provider.

I am sure there must be a simpler way to solve this that I am unaware of

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I use `IFormFile` when I want to upload files to my API. You can retrieve the file name using the `Name` property:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadProfilePic([FromForm]IFormFile uploadFile))
{
    // do something with uploadFile.Name 
}
```